# A windowed aggregation on event count

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have grouped my kafka events:

```
    private static void createImportStream(final StreamsBuilder builder, final Collection<String> topics) {
        final KStream<byte[], GraphEvent> stream = builder.stream(topics, Consumed.with(Serdes.ByteArray(), new UserEventThriftSerde()));
        stream.filter((key, request) -> {
            return Objects.nonNull(request);
        }).groupBy(
                (key, value) -> Integer.valueOf(value.getSourceType()),
                Grouped.with(Serdes.Integer(), new UserEventThriftSerde()))
              .aggregate(ArrayList::new, (key, value, aggregatedValue) -> {
                          aggregatedValue.add(value);
                          return aggregatedValue;
                      },
                      Materialized.with(Serdes.Integer(), new ArrayListSerde<UserEvent>(new UserEventThriftSerde()))
              ).toStream();
    }
```

how can I add a `window` but not based on time, but based on number of events. 
The reason is that the events will be a bulk dump, a time windowed aggregation would not fit since all events could appear in the same few seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kafka Streams does not support count-based windows out-of-the box because those are non-deterministic and it's hard to handle out-of-order data.

Instead of using the DSL, you can use the Processor API to build a custom operator for your use case though.